# React-Native ERROR Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., "myApp" has not been registered. iOS only

Tags: ios, react-native

We are facing issues when trying to build our app on iOS only.
All packages are up to date, it builds perfectly on Android, but iOS will build successfully yet throw the error:

`` ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes  LOG  Running "myApp" with {"rootTag":41,"initialProps":{}}  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "myApp" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project. * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.register component` wasn't called., js engine: hermes ``

We have tried deleting the Pods, Podfile.lock, deleting node modules, npm install --force, pod install, pod update, even pod deintegrate, pod init, everything we found a bit everywhere on Google, nothing ever worked. We are sure of the app name "myApp" (a placeholder for privacy :)), as you can see in the following files:

```
/////// Index.js /**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => App);
```

```
/////// package.json
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 14\"",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules && npm i",
    "hard-clean-ios": "cd ios && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf build && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..",
    "hard-clean-android": "rm -rf node_modules && npm i && cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
    "delete-cache": "watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "clean:ios": "rm -rf ios/build"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "BluetoothPeripheral",
    "FaceID",
    "LocationAccuracy",
    "LocationAlways",
    "LocationWhenInUse"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.16",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.14",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-bluetooth-state-manager": "^1.3.5",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.11.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-location-enabler": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.9.3",
    "react-native-rename": "^3.2.13",
    "react-native-safe-area": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.28",
    "@types/react-native-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

````
////// Podfile

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

# use_frameworks!

target 'myApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # pre_install do |installer|
  #   Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
  
  #   installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
  #     if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
  #       def pod.build_type;
  #         # Uncomment the line corresponding to your CocoaPods version
  #         # Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
  #         # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
  #       end
  #     end
  #   end
  # end

  ENVFILES = {
  'Debug' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../.env.dev',
  'Release' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../.env.prod',
}

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.name == 'react-native-config'
          config.build_settings['ENVFILE'] = ENVFILES[config.name]
        end
      end
    end
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

```
/////// AppDelegate.mm
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"myApp";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

/// This method controls whether the `concurrentRoot`feature of React18 is turned on or off.
///
/// @see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html
/// @note: This requires to be rendering on Fabric (i.e. on the New Architecture).
/// @return: `true` if the `concurrentRoot` feature is enabled. Otherwise, it returns `false`.
- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  return true;
}

@end
```

Can't figure out what we are missing. Any help would be amazing :)

Comment: Facing the same issue! Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: Yeah found it after a week on it! The issue came from the package  "react-native-location-enabler": "^4.1.1". It is not compatible with iOS and will throw an error if not conditionally called in the app using Platform.OS === "android". I just totally removed it and the error is gone. If you don't have this one installed, check for other packages :)

Comment: Oh, it sounds good! I will double-check my packages as well. Thankyou.

Comment: I have used the "react-native-android-location-enabler" module. The same compatibility issue exists with iOS. I have fixed it by checking the platform. Everything is working properly now.

Comment: @ThomasAugot how did you figure out the compatibility issue? Did go package by package or is there another way?

Comment: @AakarshKumar I had to go one by one until I found which... Good luck :)